# LINQ: Prefetching data from a second table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to pre-fetch some foreign key data using a linq query.  A quick example to explain my problem follows:

```
var results = (from c in _customers
               from ct in _customerTypes 
               where c.TypeId == ct.TypeId 
               select new Customer
                          {
                             CustomerId = c.CustomerId,
                             Name = c.Name,
                             TypeId = c.TypeId,
                             TypeName = ct.TypeName,  <-- Trying to Prefetch this
                          }).ToList();
```

The Customer class looks like:

```
[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
   [Column(Name = "CustomerId", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }

   [Column(Name = "Name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [Column(Name = "TypeId")]
   public int TypeId { get; set;}

   public string TypeName { get; set; }

   public Confession (){}
}
```

However LINQ will not let you do this throwing a NotSupportedException with "Explicit construction of entity type 'Customer' in query is not allowed."

I'm clearly approaching this incorrectly.  Any pointers in the right direction would be most helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says, you can't construct a Customer there.

The (arguably) easiest thing to do would be to create a new class that encapsulates the properties you need. You can get everything from the Customer class by doing it like this:

```
var results = (from c in _customers
               from ct in _customerTypes 
               where c.TypeId == ct.TypeId 
               select new
                      {
                         Customer = c,
                         TypeName = ct.TypeName
                      }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do genuine pre-loading, you can do the following:

(This assumes there's a join between the `Customer` and `CustomerType` tables in your database, and that LINQ to SQL knows about it.)

```
MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext(); // Use your application-specific DataContext class
DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.CustomerType);
dc.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
var results = from c in dc.GetTable<Customer>() select c;
```

You could then access the `TypeName` thus (where `c` is a `Customer` in `results`):

```
c.CustomerType.TypeName;
```